# Compilar .h dependiendo del target que se ejecute

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Tengo dos `.h` en mi proyecto con el mismo nombre auto-generados. Alguien sabe cómo compilar uno u otro dependiendo del target que se ejecute?

Es imperativo no cambiar el nombre de los `.h`

Comment: Puedes incluir la ruta del directorio en la sentencia `#import`, algo como `#import "ios/header.h"` vs `#import "osx/header.h"`

Comment: ¿Podrías poner una captura de los ficheros de tu proyecto? A priori la única solución es tener un solo `.h` y dos `.m`, ya que los `.m` son los únicos a los que les puede asignar un `target`

Comment: ¿Es cada `.h` generado en un diferente directorio pero con el mismo nombre?, o ¿es el mismo `.h` reemplazado cada vez que se cambia el target?

Comment: @rraallvv esa es la pregunta que yo me hago. Diferentes `targets` dentro de un mismo proyecto pueden tener  iguales archivos `.h` pero si están dentro del mismo `target` no...

Comment: @mhergon Creo que se podría crear un tercer `.h` para importar el que corresponde al target con un condicional en tiempo de compilación, pero solo si son dos `.h` en diferentes directorios. Si el `.h` es auto-generado dependiendo del target creo que no debería haber problema si se incluye el mismo archivo en ambos targets.

Comment: @rraallvv esa fue! gracias a todos por las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes.

Para hacer ese tipo de cosas en Obj-C se suelen usar las sentencias de precompilado.
Te explico un poco como funcionan.

Tenemos dos targets. (**Target1** y **Target2**)
En los dos targets tenemos que declarar una **macro de preprocesador**. Por ejemplo **AR_IMPORTS**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En **Target1** le daremos el valor 0 y en **Target2** le daremos el valor 1.

Los macros estos los usa el compilador para saber que ha de hacer en cada momento.

Por ejemplo podrías poner en el codigo algo así:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class IETemplate;

@interface AKREngine : NSObject

-(instancetype)initWithRules:(NSArray<NSDictionary *> *)rules;

#if AR_IMPORTS

-(void)run;

#endif

-(void)close;

@end
```

En este caso podrás comprobar que cuando la variable **AR_IMPORTS** es true, o sea, mayor que 0 el compilador compilará el método run, en caso de ser false no lo hará.